# Google Sheets. Get formula calculated values of the cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can't resolve the problem — get formula calculated value of the cell in Google Sheet. I mean, the cell don't edit — has formula, the calculated result based on other cell's values.

Example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MFIheQU7Ghdc2tPDT8PDX-twx_l18rSlTK-g3QDMKtc/

Sheet2

Get data via IMPORTRANGE. Dynamic data, changed every 10 mins. (the key of the problem is here)

Sheet1

Get data from Sheet2: VAR0, TIMESTAMP.

Has it's own data: VAR1. Preinput data, can modified.

Calculated column: CALC based on values of VAR1 and VAR0.

What I need:

When CALC calculated needed values (1 — in example), TARGET should get value from TIMESTAMP.

When CALC calculated any other values — TARGET keep the previous value (if value is empty early — null).

What I've tried:

AppsScript - pure `.getValue()` — unfortunately works only when the cell edited, not the values. It will be the great resolution, if you can offer the way to catch the cell's value modified.
`.getValue()` and cycle while — to long to run

Google Sheets Formulas

No good attempts.

Comment: About `Dinamyc data, changed every 10 mins.`, how is the Spreadsheet changed? Can I ask you about the detail of this situation?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Dinamyc data, changed every 10 mins.`, from `Collecting parsing data in CSV. Get it by AppsScript via IMPORTDATA by time Trigger.`, in your actual situation, the data of the Spreadsheet is changed every 10 minutes using the time-driven trigger of Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, how about including your expected script in the script for using the time-driven trigger? If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize.

Comment: Collecting parsing data in CSVs (more than 1). Get each of it by AppsScript via IMPORTDATA by time Trigger. After that Sheet2 consolidate all spreadsheets data via IMPORTRANGE.  
I'll be glad to answer any your question about the issue.

Comment: The problem exactly in catch values from TIMESTAMP when CALC calculated necessary value (if you can, please check the example link. Hope it's understandable one).  
I tried your suggestion using AppScript with cycle WHILE and .getValue(). But it takes a long time to work out (not critical yet, but can be a problem in close future).  
Sorry for comments mishmash — it was my first comment, it turns out they only give 5 minutes for editing.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood your expected result is as follows. You want to run a script when Sheet1 and Sheet2 of your provided Spreadsheet are updated. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, from `Get each of it by AppsScript via IMPORTDATA by time Trigger.`, how about including the script to this part? Unfortunately, I could't imaging your current script from `I tried your suggestion using AppScript with cycle WHILE and .getValue(). But it takes a long time to work out` because of my poor English skill. I apologize for this.